# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to run this command to initialize one of my database tables from a class.

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

However I am getting this error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Below are the files I have.

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using RawMealBalancer.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;

namespace RawMealBalancer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=rawmealbalancer;Trusted_Connection=True;"));
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RawMealBalancer.Data.Entities;

namespace RawMealBalancer.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext() : base()
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        // Define DbSet properties for your entity classes
        public DbSet<Food> Foods { get; set; }
        // Add other DbSet properties for your other entity classes
    }
}
```

I used the connection string provided to me when I installed SQL Server. I also tried making a new db and modifying the connection string. So far nothing has worked and ChatGPT is not helping.

I am extremely new to using entity framework and connecting to a database in an ASP.NET Core MVC project.

I tried to modify the connection string however it hasn't helped much. The DB doesn't have a password since I am just trying to figure out stuff locally right now. I am debating whether I should just throw it on the cloud because I've had better luck connecting to that.

If it is helpful this is my file structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPUvU.png)

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how you are running this command `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` - for instance, it might just be you are in the wrong "place". You have to be careful with terminals.

Comment: Move your connection string to appsetting.json and load it from there `services.AddDbContext<CompanyContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("your Connection")));`.  Check [this article.](https://www.yogihosting.com/dbcontext-entity-framework-core/).

Comment: Which version of `ASP.NET Core MVC ` you are using.  In addition, whats your server name?

Comment: Remove default constructor without parameters.

Comment: @topsail I am running the command in the dev terminal.

Comment: @yogihosting I tried it that way previously.  no change

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov .NET 6.0 and the server is hosted locally for now so I just copied the string provided by sql. Tried modifying it a bunch of different ways

Answer (score 1):

> I am extremely new to using entity framework and connecting to a
> database in an ASP.NET Core MVC project.
>
> I tried to modify the connection string however it hasn't helped much.
> The DB doesn't have a password since I am just trying to figure out
> stuff locally right now. I am debating whether I should just throw it
> on the cloud because I've had better luck connecting to that.

Well, according to your error message it seems that your database configuration   went wrong. Make sure you have installed [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore) and
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/). These should be within your projcet dependencies as following:

[image]

**Note:** Keep in mind version should be matched with your Asp.net core XX version. I am using Asp.net core 6XX.

Update Your DbContext Class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Food> Foods{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
         
            modelBuilder.Entity<Food>().ToTable("YourFoodTableNameInDatabase");
        }
       
    }
```

Apart from above steps, you could read your connction string from appsettings.json as following instead of passing database credential directly. Although, its not mandatory but recommended.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

**Note:** You can [get details steps here in the official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration)

Comment: Alright I modified those things and now I am getting this error. 

Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728


I will refer to the documentation provided and hopefully figure something out.

Comment: Also changed the entity framework and sql server versions to 6.0.16 but I think it updated after doing a clean build. My .NET version is 6.0

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, its better to have same release version.  Most importantly, entity framework and  EF sql server version should be equal or lower but cannot be higher then the asp.net core project version.